# How do you check if a input value is int and otherwise put in a loop?

Tags: python

I'm a very beginner in computer language (2 days) and am writing a basic slot machine code in python.

```
import random
import time

balance = 1000

print("Welcome to the Slot World")

player_name = input("What's your name?")


while balance > 0:

    print(player_name, ", you have $",balance, " to bet.")
    bet = int(input("How much do you want to bet?"))

    x = random.randint(1, 5)
    y = random.randint(1, 5)
    z = random.randint(1, 5)
    numbers = [x, y, z]

    if bet != int:
        print("Please enter correct amount")
        continue
    elif bet > balance:
        print("You do not have sufficient amount")
        continue
    elif bet <= 0:
        print("Please enter correct amount")
        continue
    else:
        print("You have bet $", bet)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(numbers)
        balance = balance - bet

    if x == y and y == z:
        if x == 1:
            print("Winner 20x!")
            bet = bet * 20
            balance = balance + bet
        elif x == 2:
            print("Winner 30x!")
            bet = bet * 30
            balance = balance + bet
        elif x == 3:
            print("Winner 40x!")
            bet = bet * 40
            balance = balance + bet
        elif x == 4:
            print("Winner 50x!")
            bet = bet * 50
            balance = balance + bet
        elif x == 5:
            print("Winner 100x!")
            bet = bet * 100
            balance = balance + bet

    elif x == y and not y == z:
        if x == 1:
            print("Winner 2x")
            bet = bet * 2
            balance = balance + bet
        elif x == 2:
            print("Winner 3x")
            bet = bet * 3
            balance = balance + bet
        elif x == 3:
            print("Winner 4x")
            bet = bet * 4
            balance = balance + bet
        elif x == 4:
            print("Winner 5x")
            bet = bet * 5
            balance = balance + bet
        elif x == 5:
            print("Winner 10x")
            bet = bet * 10
            balance = balance + bet

    elif not x == y and y == z:
        if y == 1:
            print("Winner 2x")
            bet = bet * 2
            balance = balance + bet
        elif y == 2:
            print("Winner 3x")
            bet = bet * 3
            balance = balance + bet
        elif y == 3:
            print("Winner 4x")
            bet = bet * 4
            balance = balance + bet
        elif y == 4:
            print("Winner 5x")
            bet = bet * 5
            balance = balance + bet
        elif y == 5:
            print("Winner 10x")
            bet = bet * 10
            balance = balance + bet

    elif not x == y and x == z:
         if x == 1:
                print("Winner 2x")
                bet = bet * 2
                balance = balance + bet
         elif x == 2:
                print("Winner 3x")
                bet = bet * 3
                balance = balance + bet
         elif x == 3:
                print("Winner 4x")
                bet = bet * 4
                balance = balance + bet
         elif x == 4:
                print("Winner 5x")
                bet = bet * 5
                balance = balance + bet
         elif x == 5:
                print("Winner 10x")
                bet = bet * 10
                balance = balance + bet

    else:
        print("Bad Luck! You Lost!")
print("You lost all your money\nThe End")
```

If I input a character for bet

```
bet = int(input("How much do you want to bet?"))
```

it gives me

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

Comment: are you providing char input.

Comment: what is your desired behavior? ask for correct input until it is not convertible to `int`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try`:

```
while True:
    try:
        bet = int(input("How much do you want to bet?"))
    except ValueError:
        print "Not valid integer"
        continue
    break
```

Comment: using `except` without specifying exception type is a bad thing to do

Comment: @Joe, add the specific Exception that is to be caught. In this case `ValueError`

Answer (score 1):

You can not change string like `a-Z` into integer so you have to check for it

```
try:
    bet = int(input("How much do you want to bet?"))
except ValueError:
    print ("Not valid integer")
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the letter `a` can't be converted to a number, because what to which number should it then convert?

So for that @Joe's answer with try `try` `except` should be perfect.

Also, it might be safer to rather convert to a `float`. It makes it more robust, you can enter decimal values if you want,

```
bet = float(input("How much do you want to bet?"))
```

Comment: If you enter the char `a` does your solution solve the problem? :)

Comment: Just realized >.<    I'm updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [int()](https://kite.com/python/docs/builtins.int) function to try to convert string value to integer. It will raise ValueError if it is not. Use `try` to catch it and use its `else` clause to break from the loop.

```
while True:
    try:
        value = int(input('Enter your number'))
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        break
```